# socket hang up error in node.js post request

Tags: node.js, parsing, post, https, push

I'm trying to wrap a POST request to Parse using node.js. I just want to send a Push notification, but  a socket hang up error keeps showing up.

- This is the REST API documentation for Parse Push: https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/REST 

  **It does work using curl and python.**
- This is the tutorial I checked to do the translation: http://tech.pro/tutorial/1091/posting-json-data-with-nodejs

And this is my code:

```
var http = require('http')

var data = {
    channels: 'a_channel',
    data: {
            alert: "Something has happened"
    }
 }

 pdata = JSON.stringify(data);

 var apiKeys =  {
   "X-Parse-Application-Id": "lol",
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "lolol",
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
    'Content-Length': pdata.length
};

 var options = {
    hostname: 'api.parse.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/1/push',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: apiKeys
};


var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
res.setEncoding('utf-8');

var responseString = '';
 res.on('data', function(data) {
 responseString += data;
  });

 res.on('end', function() {
var resultObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
   });
   });

req.on('error', function(e) {
   console.log('problem with the request, wero: ' + e.message);
});


   req.write(pdata);
   req.end();
   console.log(pdata);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the http module for doing an https call. You should require the `https` at the top.

Also be careful with `pdata` as it's missing the **`var`** keyword.